# Desplazar esta imagen hacia la derecha sin que el texto baje

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Ese es literalmente mi problema: cuando pongo la imagen, el texto del título se baja hacia abajo. He probado a ponerlo después del texto, pero no se hace así.

Mientras tanto lo he puesto abajo para que no quede tan mal. Estoy hablando todo el rato de la primera imagen de todos, las otras dos están bien.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(54, 82, 42);
}

.Parrafos {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#Londres {
  color: rgb(171, 9, 9);
}

#Toronto {
  color: rgb(171, 9, 9);
}
```

```html
<h1>Triva-go!</h1><img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/aqualine-ultimate.png" alt="Beach" width="100">

<p class="Parrafos">En nuestra página de viajes usted podrá encontrar viajes de todo tipo y ¡al mejor precio! Berlín, Moscú, Belgrado, Madrid, Londres e incluso Nueva York.
</p>

<h2 id="Londres">Londres</h2>

<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/landscapes/clouds-from-plane.png" alt="Beach" width="350">

<p> Bienvenido a Londres, la mejor ciudad del mundo Aquí encontrará algunas de las mejores galerías, museos y salas, y con el London Pass tendrá a su alcance las numerosas maravillas de la capital. Tanto si va a estar un fin de semana o una semana completa,
  hay algo especial para cada uno.</p>

<ol>
  <h3>Estas son algunas de los lugares a los que te proponemos viajar...</h3>
  <li>El Big Ben</li>
  <li>La Abadía de Westminster</li>
  <li>El Parlamento</li>
</ol>

<h2 id="Toronto">Toronto</h2>

<img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/landscapes/waterfall_niagara-falls.png" alt="Beach" width="350">
<p class="Parrafos"> Visite una megalópolis que cautiva a miles de turistas anualmente. Toronto es una ciudad asombrosa, con una diversidad de atracciones y lugares sorprendentes para visitar. Conozca sus lugares históricos, enamórese de su arquitectura y disfrute de ambientes
  multiculturales en su visita.</p>

<ol>
  <h3>Estas son algunas de los lugares a los que te proponemos viajar...</h3>
  <li>Las cataratas del niagara </li>
  <li>La torre CN </li>
  <li>ChinaTown </li>
</ol>
```

¿Cómo puedo desplazar esta imagen hacia la parte derecha de la página sin hacer que el texto baje hacia abajo?

Comment: Puedes aventarte videos sobre flex box, si sabes inglés, te recomiendo que te avientes este artículo sobre [Felxbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

html por defecto funciona de forma secuencial, es decir que cada elemento respeta la posición del siguiente elemento; estas posiciones se puede manejar mediante css tocando la propiedad position: relative, absolute, fixel, static.
Adicional cada elemento tiene una forma predeterminada de desplegarse, es decir puede ser en bloque, en linea para eso podemos tocar la propiedad display:block, inline, inline-block entre otras.

Actualmente dadas las necesidades y a las recientes versiones de css podemos hacer mucho más que eso, podemos definir las posiciones de los elementos contenidos en otros, gracias a propiedades como flexbox o grid.

Para tu caso puedes usar flexbox de la siguiente forma:

`<div class="content">
<h1>Triva-go!</h1><img src="https://www.kasandbox.org/programming-images/avatars/aqualine-ultimate.png" alt="Beach" width="100">
</div>`

y luego en tu css, puedes hacer esto:

`.content{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}`

Lo que estamos definiendo es que el .content debe comportarse diferente (caja flexible) donde tanto a el titulo h1 como a la imagen podemos manipularlas, por defecto al decir display:flex se crearan dos columnas una para el titulo y otra para el texto, y al decirle align-items: center todo el contenido quedara centrado verticalmente.

Investiga más sobre el tema espero te sirve, saludos.